# Calculus - problem with this series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have this problem, I need to find the sum:

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}*\frac{7}{6^{k-1}} = 7 + (-\frac{7}{6}) + \frac{7}{36}+...+(-1)^{k-1}*\frac{7}{6^{k-1}}$$

Consider

$$\frac{1}{6}S_n = (-\frac{7}{6}) + \frac{7}{36}+...+((-1)^{k-1}*\frac{7}{6^{k-1}})+((-1)^{k}*\frac{7}{6^{k}})$$

$$S_n-\frac{1}{6}S_n=7-((-1)^k*\frac{7}{6^k})=$$
$$\frac{5}{6}S_n=7-((-1)^k*\frac{7}{6^k})=$$
$$\frac{5}{6}S_n=\frac{7}{6}(6-(-1)^{k-1}*\frac{1}{6^{k-1}})=$$
$$S_n=\frac{7}{5}(6-(-1)^{k-1}*\frac{1}{6^{k-1}}=$$
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{7}{5}(6-(-1)^{k-1}*\frac{1}{6^{k-1}}=8.4$$

But for some reason I get the wrong answer, Anyone has an idea?

Thanks

Comment: When you write $S_n$, do you want $\sum_{k=1}^{n}$ rather than $\sum_{k=1}^\infty$? And do you want the terms to end at $n$ rather than $k$?

Comment: Use letters, not numbers, so $a+ar+\cdots+$.  Then after you get a nicce expression, let $a=7$ and $r=-1/6$. Mistakes of arithmetic are less likely. Typing is easier too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common ratio in the geometric series is $-\frac16$, not $\frac16$, so you should be multiplying $S_n$ by $-\frac16$. In the line that begins $\frac16S_n$ you’ve actually done this correctly on the righthand side but not on the lefthand side. If you fix the lefthand side, you’ll find that you have $\frac76S_n$ rather than $\frac56S_n$, and all will be well.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Geometric series with $x=(-1/6)$. Thus $$S_\infty=7\cdot\dfrac{1}{1-(-1/6)}=6$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that:

$$\ \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}\frac{7}{6^{k-1}}=7\cdot\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}\frac{1}{6^{k-1}}=7\cdot\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-\frac{1}{6})^k$$

so now you should recognize a geometric series.